# How to disable certain Fn key + F key shortcuts

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to disable specific function key shortcuts?
I have one that puts the computer to sleep whenever i press it (Fn key + F12), and i only ever hit it on accident.

I'm not asking for a way to disable them all, since there are media shortcuts i use often. I'm asking for a way to disable just one. or mutiple.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > "change when the Computer sleeps" > Advanced power settings > Power buttons > Sleep button action

Set that to "do nothing".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) macro:

```
Sleep::msgbox Sleep key is disabled.
```

But AutoHotKey help for <kbd>Sleep</kbd> key also says:

> Note that the sleep key on some keyboards might not work with this.

This means, that on some keyboards, the above macro can catch keypress of <kbd>Sleep</kbd> key and redirect its action but on other keyboards it is not possible. If you find out that your computer goes to sleep despite this macro (I found this on my Lenovo), then perhaps the only thing you can do is to completely disable sleep mode in Windows. But I am not sure if you want go that far.

**Note:** simply setting of <kbd>Sleep</kbd> key action in Power Options to **Do nothing** might not help, on my laptop this setting does *not* disable sleep button, but it still works as before. This is why I wrote that the only solution can be disabling the entire sleep mode.