# How do I disable my keyboard's sleep button?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sleep, gnome

I have a couple <kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcuts on my F1-F12 keys. <kbd>F12</kbd> is the calculator, <kbd>F11</kbd> puts my PC to sleep. The amounts I confuse those keys by accidents are astronomical.

How can I disable my suspend/sleep key entirely, or optionally map it to something else?

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1259098/how-to-disable-certain-fn-key-f-key-shortcuts) but it's Windows and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115333/how-do-i-disable-the-sleep-button-on-my-keyboard) but it doesn't work:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend "nothing"
No such key “button-suspend”
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep "nothing"
No such key “button-sleep”
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate "nothing"
No such key “button-hibernate”
```

I'm on arch-linux using Gnome 3.28.3. I checked everything in `gnome-settings` and `gnome-tweak-tool` without success. A search for `suspend` or `sleep` in `dconf-editor` comes up with only this, and I'm sure this isn't what I'm looking for:
[image]

I tried to find out the name (?) of the key using `xev`, in an attempt to give `xbindkeys` a try to re-map the key, but it doesn't work with the calculator shortcut (nothing shows up in `xev`) so I assume it won't work with the sleep one either (I'd rather not try).

Note: I do not want to disable sleep/suspend all-together. Just that special keyboard key.

**Edit:** I'm now on the newest gnome version (3.32). Issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME
GNOME 3.24 deprecated:

- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate
- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power
- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep
- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend

Try

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power **power-button-action** *'action'*

where *'action'* can be **nothing**, **suspend**, or **hibernate**

Details at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM

Comment: Tried it. Now when I press the button on my keyboard the screen goes black, then only the cursor shows, then all black again, a console window shows for a fraction of a second, all black with cursor again, then I'm back in my gnome-shell as if nothing happened. I'd certainly say this is worse than before, lol. Can this be related or is something else messing up here? Never happened before, usually just went into suspend normally. I've set it to `'nothing'`.

Answer (score 1):

easy just run in a terminal this
`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target` 
and restart your computer with this
`sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`

Comment: Consider marking this the accepted solution, as it is working in 2024

Answer (score 0):

With Dconf editor, navigate to org gnome settings-daemon plugins power. There you can change what the power button does.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a litle more?